# Data Test was in the past

Tags: python, datetime, arima

i need help plis
i'm going to model predict using ARIMA in jupyter notebook and i don't know why my data training and data test was in the past [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjdFV.png)

Comment: Can you please share your data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ArneDecker hey this is the code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eOSHUuUsS-pf1yPuaeKtqNq2C5wbvtKk?usp=sharing